# How do I get Bootstrap to span input-group-addons across two rows of inputs with proper alignment?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap to make a player game information entry box which looks like this for the time being:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon"></span>

<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="playername" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="room" maxlength="4" placeholder="Enter Room Code" /> <span class="input-group-addon btn"><strong>Play!</strong></span>
```

I would like to have text in the left input-group-addon indicating what the text fields are.  So I tried reorganizing things to group them differently which pretty much broke everything:

The Name and Room Addon fields have different widths and the ends are misaligned.

The Text fields don't extend to the right anymore.

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
<div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>Name</strong></span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="John Smith" id="playername" />
</div>
<div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>Room</strong></span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase text-center" id="room" maxlength="4" placeholder="ABCD" value="ABCD" />
</div> <span class="input-group-addon btn"><strong>Play!</strong></span>
```

The closest I could get is this:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg"> <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>Name<br/><br/>Room</strong></span>

<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="playername" placeholder="John Smith" />
<input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase text-center" id="room" maxlength="4" placeholder="ABCD" value="ABCD" /> <span class="input-group-addon btn"><strong>Play!</strong></span>
```

But on my screen there is a slight misalignment because I just added two br tags which expanded the text vertically is really hackey in terms of alignment and probably unreliable.

Is there a clean and reliable way to accomplish this?  I haven't been able to find anything in my searches.  I've tried form-groups but they don't play well with the input-groups

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edchow/zrbjewuh/) or [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4OBwBmpdHC) for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/murid/zrbjewuh/9/

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <strong>Name</strong><strong>Room</strong>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" id="playername" placeholder="John Smith" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase text-center" id="room" maxlength="4" placeholder="ABCD" value="ABCD" />
    <span class="input-group-addon btn">
        <strong>Play!</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

---

```
.input-group-addon strong {
    display: block;
}
.input-group-addon strong:first-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```